# IronPython.Modules.PythonSignal Throwing Exception when importing unittest module

Tags: unit-testing, signals, ironpython

Interesting case here:  I'm using IronPython 2.7.3 on my home machine and at work.  Import unittest works fine at home but not at work:

[image: Iron Python error]

Any idea what's going on?  The odd thing is the fact I un-installed Iron Python, re-installed, and I was able to import unittest for an hour with no problems.  I stepped out for a bit and tried to run additional tests but it is broken again.  Any idea what could be the cause?

Edit:  Followed Jeff's suggestion and the base exceptions are:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `import signal` directly and see if it still happens. Also, try running with `ipy -X:ExceptionDetail -X:ShowClrExceptions` to see if that includes any extra information.

PythonSignal has to do some P/Invoke code, which is always good for some bizarre behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the help again, Jeff.  I modified my question to show the details of the output.

Comment: Had a edit ready and lost it :/ Any hoot, yes, importing signal caused the problem today and yesterday as well.  Python Tools looks like it was installed twice in my control panel.  When I install the RC version with 2012 support, I un-installed the old one on my home box, but not on my work box.  Not sure if that had anything to do with it, but I'm re-doing the Tools and IPY install.  I'll play with  it for a few hours and see how it goes.

Comment: Looks like a GAC issue that seems to come and go. Will try to fix once and for all in 2.7.4, but for now, installing pytools first then IronPython 2.7.3 should work.

Comment: Just noticed something else today: It works fine in regards to running ipy64.exe.

Comment: Oh goody, that means it's probably to do with 32 vs 64 bit code. Those are always fun to debug.

Comment: Can you create an issue (http://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) with OS and 32/64-bit versions of both machines, as well as how you are launching it (PTVS, command line, embedded). These can be really hard to replicate so the more detail, the better.

Comment: Not a problem, I'll take care of that now.  Thanks again, Jeff.

Comment: Let me know if there is any additional information needed:  http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/33261